# How to use android's repo tool for Python?

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

I have N git repos installed in my virtualenv via `pip install -e git+https://...`.

The git repos are in this directory: `$VIRTUAL_ENV/src/`

I would like to have a tool to manage all git repos at once.

How can I manage N git repos in $VIRTUAL_ENV/src at once?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the basic repo commands:

```
mkdir myprojects
cd myprojects
repo init -u url_of_manifest.git -b manifest_branch -m manifest_xml
repo sync
```

If `manifest_branch` is `master`, `-b master` can be omitted. If `manifest_xml` is `default.xml`, `-m default.xml` can be omitted.

Besides all of you project repos, you need to maintain an extra manifest repo. The manifest repo contains manifests. Here is a manifest [sample](https://github.com/keiji/repo-sample/blob/master/default.xml) and [manifest-format](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt).

A manifest describes where to fetch the repos, which repos you want to manage and what revision each repo will checkout in what working trees. `repo sync` downloads all the git data and creates working trees with specific revisions.

Comment: Up to now I use `pip install -e git+https://...` to install my source code. Git repos are in $VIRTUAL_ENV/src after installing. I guess the `repo` tool does not use the src-directory. I guess I need to install the git repos with pip after the `repo` tool did the checkout .... I guess it should not be hard to glue the building blocks together.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool called [repo](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo). It's from google for android development.

Maybe it works for Python and virtualenv, too.